# AngularJS + Rails 4: including $location provider causes all links to stop working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In my Rails 4 app when I land on a particular page (my products#show page, ex: /products/30) and I click on any of the links on the page, the browser doesn't move. However, the URL changes with each click.

I investigated this issue and it seems like including the `$location` provider in my AngularJS controller is causing this issue, even though the browser console doesn't have any errors.

BTW, I'm only using AngularJS for 2 pages on my app, so I decided to stick with Rails routing.

In my `application.html.erb` I have `<html ng-app="ilook">`

In my `show.html.erb` I have this:

```
<div ng-controller="ProductCtrl">
{{ product }} zzz <!-- this prints 1 zzz -->
</div>
```

In my `load-angular.js` javascript file that is included by `application.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('ilook', ["ngResource"]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And in my `productscontroller.js` this works:

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', 'SingleProduct', function($scope, $resource, SingleProduct) {
  $scope.product = "1";
}]);
```

but including `$location` causes the links on my products#show to stop working:

```
app.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$resource', 'SingleProduct', function($scope, $location, $resource, SingleProduct) {
  $scope.product = "1";
}]);
```

Did I forget to include a module ? I need $location so that I can use the path /products/30 so that I can make a request to the API portion of my Rails app and grab the proper product given the ID. Using $routeParams doesn't seem to work since I'm using Rails routing and not angular. Any help would be appreciated. P.S. At first I thought it was a Turbolinks issue, but even after removing it nothing changed.

== UPDATE ==

When I remove the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` line in my config, the links work again. However, `$location.path()` returns an empty string even at `/products/30`. How would I grab the path then?

Comment: I guess not. `var app = angular.module('ilook', ["ngResource"]);` doesn't have it. I found another solution in getting the `30` of `products/30` in the URL. I'll leave this question up though in case anyone has the same issue or an answer to this issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into pretty much the same situation when using $location to process query parameters on a page that was not using ng-route.  I ended up using the following definition for html5mode and it appears to have fixed my issues with the links no longer working.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false,
    rewriteLinks: false
});
```